# How to kill an application from the ResourceManager Web UI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

Is there a way of killing an application from the RM web UI instead of running `yarn application -kill`?

Comment: Currently Web UI does not allow to kill an application!

Comment: @HamzaZafar, you are not right.

Comment: @Sergey Maybe they have added the feature in latest release! It wasn't there when this question was asked! CLI was used to kill apps back then. Thanks for pointing out the correction :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can do that in hadoop v2.7.1

1. Open `http://<host_name>:<port>/cluster/app/<app_id>`
2. Press button **Kill application**

[image]

Comment: Where to kill in Hadoop 3.0?

Answer (score 3):

You should add 
`yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.ui-actions.enabled=true`
to your 
`yarn-site.xml` to enable this button (if its not visible).